# lightning-tab embedded LWC data table issue

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, lightning-tab, lightning-tabset

I am working to embed an LWC into a lightning tab format on the Interaction__c record page I have custom components on.

The HTML for the lightning tab:

```
    <lightning-tab label="Payment Profiles" value="paymentProfileTab">
        <!-- Payment Profiles and Autopay Profiles related lists -->
        <c-demo-_-payment-profile-details
            record-id={billingAccountId}>
        </c-demo-_-payment-profile-details>
    </lightning-tab>
```

The tab appears as below in the two pictures posted, the LWC JS file that powers these tables is below:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import getPaymentsByAccount from '@salesforce/apex/DemoPaymentDetailsController.getPaymentsByAccount';
import getAutoPaymentsByAccount from '@salesforce/apex/DemoPaymentDetailsController.getAutoPaymentsByAccount';
import BILLING_ACCOUNT_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Interaction__c.Billing_Account__c';

const fields = [BILLING_ACCOUNT_FIELD];

const columns = [
    { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name' },
    { label: 'Last Used', fieldName: 'Last_Used__c', type: 'date' },
    { label: 'Payment Method', fieldName: 'Payment_Method__c' },
    { label: 'Expiration Date', fieldName: 'Expiration__c', type: 'date' },
    { label: 'Status', fieldName: 'Status__c', type: 'text' }
];

export default class DemoPaymentDetails extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId; // Holds the value of the Interaction__c record Id
    billingAccountId; // To store the Billing Account Id from Interaction__c

    showPaymentTable = true;
    showAutopayTable = true;
    paymentPlanData = [];
    autoPayData = [];
    paymentPlanColumns = columns;
    autoPayColumns = columns;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields })
    wiredRecord({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.billingAccountId = getFieldValue(data, BILLING_ACCOUNT_FIELD);
            console.log('Billing Account Id:', this.billingAccountId);
            if (this.billingAccountId) {
                this.fetchData(this.billingAccountId);
            } else {
                console.error('Billing Account Id is missing.');
            }
        } else if (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching record data:', error);
        }
    }

    fetchData(accountId) {
        console.log('Fetching data for Billing Account Id:', accountId);
        getPaymentsByAccount({ accountId })
            .then(result => {
                this.paymentPlanData = result;
                this.showPaymentTable = true;
                console.log('Payment Profiles Data:', result);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error fetching payment profiles:', error);
            });

        getAutoPaymentsByAccount({ accountId })
            .then(result => {
                this.autoPayData = result;
                this.showAutopayTable = true;
                console.log('AutoPay Profiles Data:', result);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error fetching autopay profiles:', error);
            });
    }
}
```

The output of the LWC when embedded on a standard tab is as below (expected outcome)

[image]

However, the issue here comes from the tab showing the LWC, but the apex class does not receive the Interaction__c.Billing_Account__c field at all, nor even triggers in the console when navigating to the tab.  No logs appear from my console.log as if nothing the component isn't recognized.

[image]

I am passing the the billingAccountId to the LWC but nothing seems to work to get this data to appear.

Any thoughts or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Disregard, the fix was unrealistically simple, change BillingAccountId and pass recordId instead, final code:

```
<lightning-tab label="Payment Profiles" value="paymentProfileTab">
    <!-- Payment Profiles and Autopay Profiles related lists -->
    <c-demo-_-payment-profile-details
        record-id={recordId}>
    </c-demo-_-payment-profile-details>
</lightning-tab>
```